# DataTables error after creating 50000 records

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I use DataTables in Laravel and after creating 50000 records I have this error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=employee_table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

It used to work fine when I had 200 records, but now it throws this error. How can it be fixed?
My script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('.employee_datatable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('admin.employees.index') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'image_path', name: 'image_path',  orderable: false, searchable: false},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'position', name: 'position'},
                {data: 'recruitment_date', name: 'recruitment_date'},
                {data: 'phone_number', name: 'phone_number'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'payment', name: 'payment',  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 3, '$')},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]
        });

    });
```

Index function to call the DataTable:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Employee::with('position')->select('id','name','email', 'position_id', 'image_path', 'recruitment_date',
            'phone_number', 'payment')->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('position', function (Employee $employee) {
                return $employee->position->name;
            })->addColumn('image_path', function ($data) { $url=asset("images/$data->image_path");
                return '<img src='.$url.' class="rounded-circle" width="40" align="center" />'; })
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                    $button = '<a href="/admin/employees/'. $data->id .'/edit"  class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>';
                    $button .= '        <button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"">
                     <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>';
                    return $button;
                })->rawColumns(['image_path', 'action'])
                ->make(true);
        }

        return view('admin.employees.index');

    }
```

Comment: "_please see [http://datatables.net/tn/7](http://datatables.net/tn/7)_" - did you follow the diagnosis and resolution steps described there? What were your findings?

Comment: Also, since you are using `serverSide: true`, can you confirm that your server-side logic is only sending one page of results to the browser (and not all 50,000 records)? And what does your server have to say - any error messages there?

Comment: `$data = Employee::with('position')->select('id','name','email', 'position_id', 'image_path', 'recruitment_date', 'phone_number', 'payment')->get();`

Do not use `get()` in the `$data` query for datatable, in this way the query return full table and request is timeout.

Yajratable gets the collection itself with limit if we pass the query without fetching the entire collection, like below:

`$data = Employee::with('position')->select('id','name','email', 'position_id', 'image_path', 'recruitment_date', 'phone_number', 'payment');`  @Illia

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed because of `get()` so now my index function looks like this:

```
$data = Employee::with('position')->select('id','name','email', 'position_id', 'image_path', 'recruitment_date',
            'phone_number', 'payment');
```

Thanks to Manjeet Barnala.